# How get a substring after the 3rd occurrence of a string c#

Tags: c#

How can I find use the substring method so I can get everything after the 3rd occurence of "/"
for example I have string that contains: http://TEST.COM/page/subpage

How can I extract page/subpage this from the above string (in c#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split() :

```
    // The directory 
    string dir = "http://TEST.COM/page/subpage";
    // Split on directory separator
    string[] parts = dir.Split('/');
```

And you will have an array. You can do with it what you want. And Split() string as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with URL's you can use [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
var url = new Uri("http://TEST.COM/");
var path = url.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri("http://TEST.COM/page/subpage"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be various ways:

As @Selman mentioned using Uri class:

```
var url = new Uri("http://TEST.COM/");
var path = url.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri("http://TEST.COM/page/subpage"));
```

using IndexOf

```
var offset = myString.IndexOf('/');
offset = myString.IndexOf('/', offset+1);
var result = myString.IndexOf('/', offset+1);
```